# C#(Unity) - How to stop the function execution?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have code like this one:

```
    public void Interacted(){
    if (GameObject.Find ("Sara").GetComponent<controls> ().isIntered) {
        if (Interer.name == "sinkTop" && !sinked) {
            Interer.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer> ().sprite = sinkON;
            sinked = true;
        }
        if (Interer.name == "sinkTop" && sinked) {
            Interer.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer> ().sprite = sinkOFF;
            sinked = false;
        }
    }
}
```

How do I stop `Interacted()` execution inside `if (Interer.name == "sinkTop" && !sinked)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `return` at the end inside `if`:

```
if (Interer.name == "sinkTop" && !sinked) 
{
    Interer.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer> ().sprite = sinkON;
    sinked = true;
    return;         //return here.
}
```

or add `else` before second `if`:

```
if (Interer.name == "sinkTop" && !sinked) 
{
    Interer.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer> ().sprite = sinkON;
    sinked = true;
}
else if (Interer.name == "sinkTop" && sinked) 
{
    Interer.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer> ().sprite = sinkOFF;
    sinked = false;
}
```

Also, you can refactor your code:

```
if (Interer.name == "sinkTop") 
{
    if (sinked)
    {
        Interer.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer> ().sprite = sinkOFF;
        sinked = false;
    }
    else
    {
        Interer.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer> ().sprite = sinkON;
        sinked = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: LOL. I tried `return;` before and it didn't work but after you answered I tried it again and it worked. Thanks anyway

Comment: @Sharpy, you are welcome.